# How can I disable xinerama?

Tags: xorg, nvidia, xinerama

I don't think it is running, but according to a bug report and a forum post (I'll add the links later) disabling it should stop skype from crashing. Is there a way to know if it is enable, and if it is to disable it?

**I'm on an nvidia card, using twinview. There should not be any xinerama btw.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine if it is enabled by viewing your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file. It will look something like this:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection
```

Notice the second last line `"Xinerama" "0"`. This indicates that it is disabled.

Comment: I checked it and it says it's off, as I figured. This means I need to check somewhere else